# VBA ammendment to code. Column Heading Changes for different Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, text

I hope you can help. I have a some code below which works fine. What it does is opens up a dialog box allows a user to select an excel file, once this file is selected.

The code looks through the column headings find the Text **"CountryCode"** then cuts this column puts it into Column F then separates column F into new worksheets based on the country.

This issue I am facing is that sometimes the  the column I want to cut contains the text **"ClientField10"** or **"ClientField1"**

So what I would like the macro to do is search the column headings for **"CountryCode"** if this is found fine execute the rest of the code.

If it is **NOT** found search for **"CleintField10"** then if found execute and if neither **"CountyCode"** or **"CleintField10"** is found search for **"CleintField1"** then execute the rest of the code

My code is below as always any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant
Dim my_Workbook As Workbook

  MsgBox "Pick your TOV file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

  my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

  If my_FileName <> False Then
    Set my_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)

    Call Sample(my_Workbook) '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

    Call Filter(my_Workbook) '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

  End If
End Sub

Public Sub Sample(my_Workbook As Workbook)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
  Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
  Dim colName As String

  '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
  Set ws = my_Workbook.Sheets(1)
  With ws
    Set aCell = .Range("A1:BB50").Find(What:="CountryCode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
      '~~> Cut the entire column

      aCell.EntireColumn.Cut

      '~~> Insert the column here

      Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Else
      MsgBox "Country Not Found"
    End If
  End With
End Sub

Public Sub Filter(my_Workbook As Workbook)
  Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range

  With my_Workbook.Sheets(1) '<--| refer to data worksheet
    With .UsedRange
      Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
    End With

    With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Q" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
      .Columns(6).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 6th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
      Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
      For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
        .AutoFilter 6, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (6th column) with current unique country name
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
          Worksheets.Add Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) '<--... add new sheet
          ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
          .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
        End If
      Next
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
  End With
  helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I didn't get to test my code before, I made the silly mistake of using  "If" instead of an "ElseIf" statements. I tested the below code and now it works.

```
Sub test()
Dim acell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)    'define ws
Set acell = ws.Range("A1:BB50").Find(What:="CountryCode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)    'define acell as location of "countrycode"

If Not acell Is Nothing Then     'if address is found do the cut & insert of that column
  acell.EntireColumn.Cut
  Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ElseIf acell Is Nothing Then         'if address is not found redefine acell to look for "clientfield10"
    Set acell = ws.Range("A1:BB50").Find(What:="ClientField10", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not acell Is Nothing Then    'if address is found do the cut & insert
        acell.EntireColumn.Cut
        Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ElseIf acell Is Nothing Then    'If not found redefine acell again to look for "ClientField1"
           Set acell = ws.Range("A1:BB50").Find(What:="ClientField1", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
           MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not acell Is Nothing Then    'If found do cut and insert
            acell.EntireColumn.Cut
            Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Else: MsgBox "Country Not Found"    'If none can be found display msgbox
            End If
    End If
End If    'close all the If loops
End Sub
```

I will delete my old answer to make this thread easier to understand

Comment: Truly awesome work here my friend. What a way to start off my Monday. Thank you so much for your assistance. The worked like a charm. Much respect from Dublin. Thank you :-)